# How does Java saving object reference work?

Tags: java, object, reference

```
    String a = "test";
    String b = a;

    a = "wuut";

    System.out.println(b);
```

Prints out `test`

Shouldn't `b` hold refence of `a`, not just take its value?

Doesn't Java work that way with objects and stuff?

Comment: Search for String Immutability on Google.. You will get so many examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `a` is created lets say it point to place `memory_1` in memory.

When `b` is assigned to `a`, then `b` also points to the same `memory_1` location.

Now, when `a` changes value (and because the String Object is immutable) a new value is created now in memory and now `a` points in `memory_2`.

But hey, `b` still points in `memory_1`.

PS: [Immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is:

> In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

Comment: Is it same for other objects also?

Comment: In java most Objects are not immutable. Examples of immutable objects from the JDK include String and Integer. (not `int` which is a primitive data type but Object `Integer` )

Comment: The behaviour here has *nothing* to do with immutability. It's a complete red herring. When `a` changes value, it changes value. It refers to a different object. There's nothing string-specific about that.

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't b hold refence of a, not just take its value?

No. The value of `a` *is* a reference. References are a way of getting to *objects*, not *variables*. The assignment operator just copies the value of the expression on the right hand side into the variable on the left hand side. That's all it does - it's very simple. There's no pass-by-reference in Java, no variable aliasing etc.

Comment: But isn't String object? Or String is special object? When I create my objects, will it work then?

Comment: @Jaanus: Yes, String is an object. But the value of `a` isn't a `String` object. It's a *reference* to a `String` object. All your classes will work in exactly the same way.

Comment: So String is like singleton ? And it holds like lots of values or smthin? When I have `MyObject a = new MyObject()`, and when I create `Myobject b = a`, then it is reference, and changing `a` also changes `b`?

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = test
```

So `a` is an `Object Reference Variable` pointing to a String Literal **"test"** on the heap.

```
String b = a;
```

No `b` is an `Object Reference Variable` also pointing to the **same** String Literal **"test"** on the heap.

Now,

```
a = "wuut";
```

But `b` is **still pointing** to the String Literal **"test"**,

**so Its b which holds the reference to the Object which was previously also referred by a, and but Not to a.**

Comment: @Ya thats what i mean...... cause its obvious that why i made it bold, still if its hard to read...let me edit it

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. `b` assumes the *value* of `a`. If `a` changes later, `b` doesn't. It's not an alias or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "test";
```

Now a holds a reference to the string "test".

```
String b = a;
```

The value of a is copied to b. A is a reference to "test", so now b is a reference to "test" too.

```
a = "wuut";
```

Now a is assigned a reference to "wuut". This doesn't affect b, because b doesn't hold a reference to a.

Answer (score 0):

No. `b` holds the value of `a` which is a reference to the string `"test"`. What you're thinking about is if you modified the string that a pointed to that `b` would also change (something like `a.append("wuut");`). However it is not possible to change Java string because they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this step by step.

1. `String a = "test"` - create object `"test"` and reference `a` point on this object.
2. `String b = a` - create new reference `b` point to the same object `"test"`
3. `a = "wuut"` - reassign reference `a` to another object, but reference `b` still point to object `test`